# Djangoチュートリアル２: 「API で遊んでみる」でエラー

Tags: python, django

Python初心者です。Djangoの[チュートリアル](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/)を進めているのですが、IDLEでpollsを呼び出すところで以下のエラーで出てしまいます。

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
　　Traceback (most recent call last):
　　File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
 　 from polls.models import Question, Choice
　　ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'
```

やったこととしては、`mysite/urls.py`の`INSTALLED_APPS`を以下のように変更しました。

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

コマンドライン（？）も以下を実行しました。

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001
python manage.py migrate
```

エラーの原因はなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Django のバージョンが古いからかもしれません。 Django のバージョンが 1.9 より古い場合はこのエラーが出ます。`python manage.py --version` で Django のバージョンが確認できるので、確かめてみてください。

参考: [ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27139) -- Django tickets #27139

Comment: version
2.0.1
と表示されたのでバージョンに関しては問題ないようです。
ちなみにですが、自分のつくったモジュール（polls)をインポートできるようになるというのは、どういう仕組みなんでしょうか？

Comment: terminalでmanage.pyをつかってIDLEを起動しないといけないようでした。Terminalから
python manage.py shell
のコマンドラインを使うことで無事インポートできました。
詳しくはわかりませんが、ディレクトリの場所の問題だったと思います。

Comment: @Goma0925 よろしければ是非[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をお願いいたします :)